# ActiveRecord belongs_to reverse mapping. Getting symbol associated with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model say Issue(ActiveRecord)
it has some fields viz. priority_id, status

```
:status, :class_name => 'IssueStatus', :foreign_key => 'status_id'
```

is there a way to know at run time- a field belongs to what model?

in above example, how to know the *symbol* associated with :foreign_key => 'status_id'

for instance, i want to get *:status* and i have 'status_id' at run time

comments please.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `issue.status.class` to show the class of the `status` field (where `issue` is an object of the `Issue` model), Note that this is not specific to ActiveRecord, you can call the `class` method on any object to find it's class/type.

Comment: thnx for response, but at run time i have status_id not status. and yes class is for any object.